# Split text into words ignoring the single quoted word in text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript

I am trying to split text into words on the basis of space but I don't want to split words in single quotes into different words.

[image]

Here if you can see word 'fd f df' is converted into three words 'fd , f , df'
but I want to get this as single word like 'fd f df'.

```
const str = `TEST = 'fd f df' AND Pitch = 444`
str.split(/\s+/)
// ["TEST", "=", "'fd", "f", "df'", "AND", "Pitch", "=", "444"]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S : this quoted words could be repeated in text many time in any position.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using regex, in the example below the first part of the regex matches anything between the quotes and the 2nd part of the regex matches anything but spaces

```js
const str = `TEST = 'fd f df' AND Pitch = 444`

console.log(str.match(/('.*?'|[^\s]+)/g));
```

Comment: This is great if there's only one quoted section, but won't work for _repeated_ quoted words.

Comment: fixed it, with the lazy quantifier, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski can you please update regex with lazy quantifier , I don't have that much good understanding of regex.
Thanks

Comment: I already did it's the `?` in the first part of the regex